# field embedding proof

Tags: field-theory

I'm reading F. Oggier's [Introduction to Algebraic Number Theory](https://feog.github.io/ANT10.pdf) and got lost at Proposition 1.7.

> Proposition 1.7. Let $K$ be a number field, $L$ be a finite extension
> of $K$ of degree $n$, and $\bar K$  be an algebraic closure of $K$.
> There are $n$ distinct $K$-monomorphisms of $L$ into $\bar K$.
>
> Proof. This proof is done in two steps. In the first step, the claim
> is proved in the case when $L = K(α)$, $α \in L$. The second step is a
> proof by induction on the degree of the extension $L/K$ in the general
> case, which of course uses the first step. The main idea is that if $L= K(α)$
> for some $α\in L$, then one can find such intermediate extension, that is, we can consider the tower of extensions
> $K\subset K(α)\subset L$, where we can use the first step for $K(α)/K$ and the
> induction hypothesis for $L/K(α)$.
>
> Step 1. Let us consider $L = K(α)$, $α\in L$ with minimal polynomial
> $f(X)\in K[X]$.   It  is  of  degree  $n$  and  thus  admits  $n$
> roots  $α_1, \cdots , α_n$  in $\bar K$ ,  which  are all distinct by
> Lemma 1.6. For $i = 1, \cdots , n$, we thus have a $K$-monomorphism
> $σ_i : L\rightarrow \bar K$  such that $σ_i(α) = α_i$.
>
> Step 2. ...

I'm confused in Step 1 -- seems the only monomorphisms from $L$ to $\bar K$ fixing $K$ are those isomorphisms from $L$ to itself, mapping $\alpha$ to any of the $n$ roots. But, is it possible to have a $\bar K \ni \beta \notin L$, so that mapping $\phi$ can be a $K$-monomorphism such that $\phi(\alpha) = \beta$?

Comment: Your problem begins where you wrote "isomorphisms from  to itself, mapping  to any of the  roots." The trouble is that you don't know that all $n$ of the roots (in $\bar K$) are in $L$. Those roots that are in $L$ will indeed give isomorphisms from $L$ to itself, but other roots can give isomorphisms from $L$ to other subfields of $\bar K$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass thank you. But.. then it seems the proof above is incomplete as it only proves the existence of such $n$ mapping, but did not prove the nonexistent of others, is that so?

Comment: Any embedding has to take $\alpha$ to a root of $f(X)$ (because the embedding fixes all elements of $K$, including the coefficients of $f(X)$). And any embedding is determined by where it sends $\alpha$ (because $L$ is generated by $K$ and $\alpha$).